# Escape character for a String in Spark-Sql

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I did my 2 hours spark documentation reading , before posting this question.

I have a Spark dataframe. which has 9 columns. I want to filter the data on 3 columns(A,B,C) which has String - "None" in it. I tried doing it using filter option. It works for individual columns but not group of columns.

```
val cleanedDF = joinedDF
  .filter(joinedDF("A") !== ("None")
  .joinedDF("B") !== ("None")
  .joinedDF("C") !== ("None"))
```

this works for individual columns, but how can I have something for a group of columns? i.e only filter out columns if all the columns has "None" in it like below. Is it possible?

```
val cleanedDF = joinedDF.filter(
  joinedDF("A") !== ("None") and
  joinedDF("B") !== ("None") and
  joinedDF("C") !== ("None"))
```

what I've also tried was converting to SQL template and querying it. But Since my filter option is a string i cant use it in the where clause. Could someone also tell me what is the correct escape character in `spark-sql`?

Example:

```
joinedDF.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT *  FROM df where B = `None` " ).show()
```

Any suggestions or help appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With DataFrame API:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("None", "a", "b"), ("c", "None", "d"), ("e", "f", "None"), ("g", "h", "i")
)).toDF("A", "B", "C")

df.where(($"A" !== "None") && ($"B" !== "None") && ($"C" !== "None")).show

// +---+---+---+
// |  A|  B|  C|
// +---+---+---+
// |  g|  h|  i|
// +---+---+---+
```

with SQL:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")

val query = """SELECT * FROM df 
               WHERE A != "None" AND B != "None" AND C != "None""""

sqlContext.sql(query).show

// +---+---+---+
// |  A|  B|  C|
// +---+---+---+
// |  g|  h|  i|
// +---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This solved my problem. I also understood that this can also be done using filter as shown in my question.

Comment: Yes, these methods should be equivalent here.